# CSS for dropdown menus both centered and to the left

Tags: css

I recently took over a friend's site and have been having a fun (read: not fun) time dealing with the theme that was built for it. My current issue are the menus. The first tier of the dropdown menu is centered, which is fine, but the second is pushed to the right, which is a problem with this theme. Since the menu is easier to fix, that's what I am trying to attack, but I CANNOT figure out what to change to push the menu to the left.

Here is my current CSS:

```
    .menu-maine-menue-container {
width: 990px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-weight: bold;

}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul {
 clear:left;
   float:left;
 list-style:none !important; 
   margin:0;
        padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;

}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li {
 list-style:none !important; 
 position:relative;
   right:50%;
   padding: 0px 22px 8px 22px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
color: #fbfbd5;
text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 2px 2px 0px;
font-family: 'Sohoma';
font-size: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .05em;

}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li:first-child {
 padding-left: 0px ;
} 



.menu-maine-menue-container ul li a {
color: #fbfbd5;
}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li a:hover {
color: #d5f4ed !important;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 2px 2px 3px;
}

.current-menu-item a, .menu-maine-menue-container ul li a:active {
color: #d5f4ed !important;

}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li a:active {
text-shadow: none !important;
}


/* SUB MARINE MENUZ */


.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul {
list-style: none;
margin:0; /* Appear just below the hovering list */
padding:0;
width:220px; /* specify the width. */
position:absolute; /* needed */
z-index:500; /* specify the order */

}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li ul {
top:27px; /* Positioning:Calc with top level horz list height */

}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul ul {
top:0;
left:100%; /* Position the sub menus to left. */
}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li ul li {
float:left; 
   padding: 12px 8px 9px 8px !important;
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
background: #eb5a4e;
width: 200px;
text-align: center !important;
}

 .menu-maine-menue-container ul li ul li:last-child {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-maine-menue-container ul li li a {
font-size: 17px;          
line-height: 19px;
text-align: center !important;
width: 200px;
}


/* Drop Down! */

/* Hide all the dropdowns (submenus)  */
.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul,
.menu-maine-menue-container ul li:hover ul ul,
.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul li:hover ul ul
{ display: none;}

/* Display the submenus only when li are hovered */
.menu-maine-menue-container ul li:hover ul,
.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul li:hover ul ,
.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul li ul li:hover ul
{ display: block;}
```

The site is [freejeremy.net](http://freejeremy.net/) and the area of issue is "Support" and "Prisoner Soldarity."

Comment: jsFiddle or site link please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule you need to change is `.menu-maine-menue-container ul ul ul` which has `left:100%`

Change the `100%` to `-50%` (*or something similar*) and you should be fine..

Comment: Removed my answer in favour of this.